# Copy plot area not working properly in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've pieced together the following code to copy the format of a chart from one chart to another. The code is still messy as I'm trying to come up with the best way of referencing the charts (any ideas welcome!).

I'm having trouble making an exact copy of the format and positions mainly of the plot area and secondary access.

You must have two charts on a page, select the source first and then the destination.  For now, they should be the same type.

Thanks for your help.

```
Sub CopyChartFormat()

' Define the source and destination charts
Dim sourceChart As Chart
Dim destChart As Chart

'Check if two charts are selected
If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type <> ppSelectionShapes Then
    MsgBox "Please select two charts."
    Exit Sub
End If

If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count <> 2 Then
    MsgBox "Please select two charts."
    Exit Sub
End If

Set sourceChart = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart
Set destChart = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2).Chart
    
''    If .HasChart = True Then
''    End If

    '' Chart size
    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2).Width = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Width
    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2).Height = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Height
    
'' Adjust plot area size and fill

    With destChart.PlotArea
        .Top = sourceChart.PlotArea.Top
        .Left = sourceChart.PlotArea.Left
        .Height = sourceChart.PlotArea.Height
        .Width = sourceChart.PlotArea.Width
    
''        .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = sourceChart.PlotArea.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
''        .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = sourceChart.PlotArea.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
    
    
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Suggestion: in order to get an answer to a specific problem with your code, reduce your example code to the simplest/shortest version that will reliably reproduce the problem.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Using Office's Chart Templates feature would simplify this a lot. To save a chart as a template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.chart.savecharttemplate To apply that template to a chart: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.applycharttemplate

Comment: @JohnKorchok i would like to try to do it this way to make it simpler for my users.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you ask users to apply chart templates. You create and apply the chart templates with VBA code. Your users will not know the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the inside of the plot area. I added as many things as I could imagine. I tested and, if the font size is different, I had to run it twice to get the wanted results.

```
Sub CopyChartFormat()

' Define the source and destination charts
Dim sourceChart As Chart
Dim destChart As Chart

'Check if two charts are selected
If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type <> ppSelectionShapes Then
    MsgBox "Please select two charts."
    Exit Sub
End If

If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count <> 2 Then
    MsgBox "Please select two charts."
    Exit Sub
End If

Set sourceChart = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart
Set destChart = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2).Chart
    
''    If .HasChart = True Then
''    End If

    '' Chart size
    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2).Width = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Width
    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2).Height = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Height
    
'' Adjust plot area size and fill

    With destChart.PlotArea
        .Top = sourceChart.PlotArea.Top
        .Left = sourceChart.PlotArea.Left
        .Height = sourceChart.PlotArea.Height
        .Width = sourceChart.PlotArea.Width
        
        
        .InsideWidth = sourceChart.PlotArea.InsideWidth
        .InsideHeight = sourceChart.PlotArea.InsideHeight
        .InsideLeft = sourceChart.PlotArea.InsideLeft
        .InsideTop = sourceChart.PlotArea.InsideTop

        End With
        
        With destChart.Format
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = sourceChart.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = sourceChart.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name
        End With
        
        

''        .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = sourceChart.PlotArea.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
''        .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = sourceChart.PlotArea.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
    
    
'    End With
    
    With destChart.ChartTitle.Format
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = sourceChart.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size
    End With
    
    With destChart.ChartArea.Format
    
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = sourceChart.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size
        
    End With
    
    
    With destChart.Legend
        .Position = sourceChart.Legend.Position
        .Left = sourceChart.Legend.Left
        .Top = sourceChart.Legend.Top
        .Width = sourceChart.Legend.Width
        .Height = sourceChart.Legend.Height
    End With


'With destChart.Floor   'commented out as i keep on getting "Method failed"
'
'.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = sourceChart.Floor.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size
'
'End With

With destChart.Format
.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = sourceChart.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size

End With


End Sub
```