# Linked chart in PowerPoint do not update when changing the lenght/range of time axis in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have several Excel charts linked to a PowerPoint presentation. When updating the charts with new data - the linked chart in PowerPoint also updates. But if i want to extend the period on the horizontal axis (e.g. expand the range to include more dates), the linked chart won't update as the Excel chart do.

Just to accept this or are there any workarounds?

Comment: Try and have a look at https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-automatically-adjust-chart-y-axis-min-and-max-values and at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75985703/copy-plot-area-not-working-properly-in-powerpoint-vba/76024038#76024038

Comment: *But if i want to extend the period on the horizontal axis (e.g. expand the range to include more dates),* I can't understand. 
What the axis is.<https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/change-the-display-of-chart-axes-422c97af-1483-4bad-a3db-3a9ef630b5a9> is this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to paste the chart with ctrl+alt+v into the pptx from the xlsx, and choose the option of copy with link. Do not use the other options which states something about link data to source because it will keep the range the same size as when the paste is done.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long time ago but I might have a workaround for this as I have the same issue.
My idea is to link to PPT a table which will be behind the chart.
In that case it is absolutely necessary that the chart will never move!
And in that case, the chart will be displayed (and not the table)

1: Create a table
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiL8W.png)

2: Select all the cells and give the table a name:
[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0azU3.png)

3:Copy the table and Paste Special in Powerpoint:
[Picture3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NccXD.png)

4: Move the Chart in Excel exactly above the table you designed

5: Refresh in Powerpoint
-> Right click on the table (but not always there) and refresh
or you can go in File -> Info -> Edit Links to Files -> Update Now

For me it works 100% !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).